# List all registered JMX Beans

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, mbeans

Can anyone give a hint on how to retrieve all registered JMX Beans within a java application.
I can use an application motitoring tool such as `jconsole` where I can see all my managed beans but what I'm looking for is an out-of-the-box tool that gives managed beans in a **text-style** list.

**Note:** I'm runnig a web app hosted in a Tomcat AS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMXTerm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/manual) seems to be the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for!!! Too strange that I can't get to the link when googling "list available jmx beans"!
Many many thanks